# Textbook proof for uniqueness of inverse in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

*A Textbook of Abstract Algebra* by Pinter gives the following proof of the property that an element in a group can have only one inverse (consider $*$ to be the operation and $e$ to be the identity element):

> Suppose an element $a$ has two inverses, $a_1$ and $a_2$.
>
> Then, $a_1*(a*a_2) = a_1*e = a_1$, and
>
> ($a_1*a)*a_2 = e*a_2 = a_2$

The book then says by associativity, the two-left hand sides are equal, and hence so are $a_1$ and $a_2$.

I have an objection to this proof. The identity element is defined as $a*e=a$, and since commutativity is not necessary in a group, the argument that $e*a_2 = a_2$ doesn't look watertight to me.

Any comments?

Comment: Ah, thank you! That made me recheck the definitions and this indeed is the case. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Irrespective of whether the group is commutative or not, $aa^{−1}=a^{−1}a=e$ and that's why the relation which you mentioned commutes.

$$aa^{−1}=e  \implies a=e\cdot a $$ $$\text{ and }$$ $$ a^{−1}a=e \implies a=a\cdot e$$

Comment: I don't understand the last two relations, though. How does $a*a^{-1}=e$ imply that $a = e*a$?, etc.

Comment: Start with $a*a^{-1} = e$, multiply both sides on the right by $a$, and then associate to get $a*e = e*a$.

Comment: Btw, you can use `\implies` to get $\implies$.

Comment: @BenWest Oh, cool! Thanks a lot for the tip. :) I always used `\Rightarrow`

Answer (score 1):

If you have already proven that the identity is unique in a group, then you can use $$e*a=a*e=a$$ for all $a\in G$.